# How do I get TFS wiki page attachment over API

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I need to download TFS wiki page attachment via the TFS API.

From MS Docs, it looks like the API alows to [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)  it but I can't seem to find a way to *get* it.

Calling GET on `/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wikiIdentifier}/pages/{pageId}/attachments/{attachmentId}` returns `Method not allowed`

Then I tried to use the WIT attachments API `/_apis/wit/attachments/{id}` but that one does not find the attachment and returns 404. (I suspect it can access only work items attachments.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `GitHttpClient.GetItemContentAsync({project}, {repositoryId}, path:{path})`

where

`path` is `"/.attachments/my attached file-89553727-xxx-yyy-zzz-829fbe167411.docx"` as found in the wiki page content (note the leading `/`)

Found this completely by accident once I moved to experimenting with `GitHttpClient` and listed all items in my repo. One of the items was an attachment and it had this path populated which I then plugged into the `GetItemContentAsync` method and voila.

My piece of code:

```cs
var uri = new Uri(_tfsBaseUri);
var credentials = GetCredentials();

using (var tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri, credentials))
{
    var wikiClient = tpc.GetClient<WikiHttpClient>();
    var gitClient = tpc.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();

    var mypage = wikiClient.GetPageAsync(_tfsProject, _tfsWiki, "My page name", includeContent: true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    var pageContent = mypage.Page.Content;
    if (pageContent.Contains("(.attachments"))
    {
         var path = "";// parse out the attachment path
         var attachmentContent = gitClient.GetItemContentAsync(_tfsProject, new Guid("_tfsWiki repo ID"), path: path).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}

private static VssCredentials GetCredentials()
{
    return new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials));
}
```

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT will do but I can't until the questions is at least 48 hours old (since it's my own answer)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the TFS/Azure DevOps Server Wiki are just Git repos, so if you want you can clone them and get all the content by using

```
Git clone "https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_git/{projectName}"
```

If it's the default project wiki.  If you want to get a wiki based on a git repo, then you just clone the repo in question and get the content.

Update:

Your attachments will be in the .attachments folder.